# Who cleans the Personals on Aurora?

Tags: isaac-asimov, robot-series, the-robots-of-dawn

In *The Robots of Dawn*, Baley invites Daniel into the Personal, to which Daniel says

> "It would not be appropriate for me to enter. It is not the custom for robots to enter the Personal. The interior of such a room is purely human."

*(For those who don't know: a Personal is a Restroom or Water Closet).*

Later, at the Robotics Institute, Baley requests access to a Community Personal. When they arrive the following dialogue takes place.

> Giskard: "Sir, we may not enter with you."
>   Baley: "Yes, I am aware of that, Giskard."
>   Giskard: "We will not be able to guard you properly, sir."

Giskard and Daneel decide they must allow Baley enter the Personal without their protection.

> When he reached the door of the structure, Daneel wordlessly indicated the contact that would open it. Daneel did not venture to touch the contact himself. Presumable, thought Baley, to have done so without specific instructions would have indicated an intention to enter—and even the intention was not permitted.

Even with their strict instructions for the protection of Baley, they would not so much as enter the Personal (unless an immediate danger was recognized). So are there other non-humanoid robots that do the cleaning, are the Personals self cleaning, or do humans do that work?

Answer (score 5):

It's not addressed in the book, but from this...

Ch. 7 *Again, Falstolfe*

> It gleamed somehow with hygienic cleanliness. Its outermost molecular
>   layer might have been peeled off after every use and a new layer laid
>   on. Obscurely, Baley felt that, if he stayed on Aurora long enough, he
>   would find it difficult to readjust himself to Earth’s crowds, which
>   forced hygiene and cleanliness into the background—something to pay a
>   distant obeisance to—a not quite attainable ideal.

and this...

Ch. 14 *Again Amadiro*

> “Could you show me that you are also superior to this planet’s
>   prejudice against robots—”
>  “There is no prejudice against robots,”
>   said Amadiro quickly.
>  Baley nodded his head solemnly in apparent
>   acceptance of the remark and completed his sentence. “—by allowing
>   them to enter the Personal with me. I have grown to feel uncomfortable
>   without them.”
>  For one moment, Amadiro seemed shaken. He recovered
>   almost at once and said, with what was almost a scowl, “By all means,
>   Mr. Baley.”
>  “Yet whoever is now inside might object strenuously. I
>   would not want to create scandal.”
>  “No one is in there. It is a
>   one-person Personal and, if someone were making use of it, the in-use
>   signal would indicate that.”
>  “Thank you, Dr. Amadiro,” said Baley.
>   He opened the door and said, “Giskard, please enter.”
>  Giskard
>   clearly hesitated, but said nothing in objection and entered. At a
>   gesture from Baley, Daneel followed, but as he passed through the
>   door, he took Baley’s elbow and pulled him in as well.

...it's established that first, cleanliness is of paramount importance to the Spacers and second, that high-order robots **can** be ordered into the Personals. There's also the First Law of Robotics, which stresses "...or through **inaction**, allow a Human to be harmed...". I think cleaning the Personals, as a disease-prevention measure, would come under that provision of the first law. So the prohibition against entering the Personals is more flexible than might be thought at first reading.
At any rate, the question of "Who cleans the Personals" has no canon, in-universe explanation. But from the general level of Spacer tech, they're either self-cleaning, or it's done by (simple) robots under strict orders never to enter with or be *seen* to enter by a human, and never, ever talk about it unless that would violate the first law.